# how to get off-page menu for responsive view to work?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, responsive-design, navigation

i cant seem to get the menu to work. i need it to be off-page before click, then come into view after clicked.

currently, I've set the menu to be 200px offpage, but i can't seem to get it to come into view upon clicking.

my website is at http://multisite.thesuit.sg/tatwai-r1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd try some Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("nav-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (document.getElementById("main-nav").style.right == undefined){  
        document.getElementById("main-nav").style.right = "200px";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("main-nav").style.right = "0px";
    }
});
```

Comment: Whoops, let me edit the code quickly, need double == instead of single in the if condition. Also you might need either a second event listener on the X button to close it correctly, or make this info a function and place onclick on both buttons.

Comment: i'm new to this, can you let me know what code to put?

Comment: Use the edited code above and let me know if that works